# Calling decorated external functions

Tags: python, decorator

I am looking for a way for a script to execute some functions for which I don't know the names and defined on another module (supposedly provided by another user), but decorated with ones that I define.

For example, the external script would be:

```
    from MyScript import preprocess, process, postprocess 

    @preprocess(foo, bar)
    def external_provider_random_name():
        return "foo"

    @process(foobar)
    def external_provider_random():
        return "bar"

    @postprocess(foo, bar)
    def external_provider():
        return "foobar"
```

I would in turn import this in my application and execute the functions ( I don't know their name), with the ability to use what the decorated function returns.

The reason I thought of decorators is become flask seems to expose the similar behavior: 
the user can define new route by decorating a function with `$@app.route(my/route)`. This function is then executed when a http call is performed on the route, and the application can use whatever the function returns (a json) to return it to the user.

However it seems that behavior doesn't fit with the actual definition of decorators, and I can't see how I can achieve such. Am I missing something here or is there a solution using only decorators ?

Comment: Note that adding `function = decorator(function)` after a function is equivalent to adding `@decorator` before it.

Comment: That's how I could add operations around the function call. But still I can't figure how to call the function in the first place, because I have no access to its name.

Comment: You don't need the name of a function to call it.  You just need a reference to the function, which is exactly what gets passed to your decorator.

Comment: How can I access it outside of the definition of my decorating function (like preprocess in the example ) ?

Comment: Basically your decorator has to store the function in a registry somewhere.  There is no magic facility decorators provide for doing this; you just have to write a decorator yourself that does something like `my_registry.append(func)` (where `my_registry` is some list of functions you created, and `func` is the function being decorated).

Comment: Fundamentally, the flask `app` object is not a mere decorating function, it is a giant class. the [`app.route`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1156) **method** is the actual decorator, and it basically [adds the function you are calling to a registry](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L384).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to squirrel away a copy of the passed-in function from inside your wrapper. You could store the function references in a global name, in a `list`, a `dict` or any other way you choose.

Here is an example of `MyScript.py` that stores its function references in a `dict`:

```
funcs = { }

def preprocess(*args):
    def wrapper(fn):
        funcs['preprocess'] = fn
        return fn
    return wrapper

def process(*args):
    def wrapper(fn):
        funcs['process'] = fn
        return fn
    return wrapper

def postprocess(*args):
    def wrapper(fn):
        funcs['process'] = fn
        return fn
    return wrapper
```

After all of the initialization, you can invoke the functions thusly:

```
MyScript.funcs['preprocess']()
```

Comment: At this point, just like in `flask`, it may make sense to use a class to encapsulate state, where the decorator callable is actually a method on an object.

Comment: Agreed. I just chose a global `dict` as an easy-to-understand example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are want to create some sort of function registry. Here's a simple example implementation that uses a dictionary to keep track of the registered functions.

```
class Tracker(dict):
    def register(self, identifier):
        def wrapper(function):
            self[identifier] = function
            return function
        return wrapper


tracker = Tracker()

@tracker.register('A')
def function_A():
    print('Blah')

tracker['A']() # Blah
```

If you want to register an already defined function, you can use:

```
tracker.register('A')(function_A)
```

Comment: I like that idea a lot. How would this work if the definition of function_A were outside of the script, on an external one - let's call it external.py ?

Comment: @AugBar I'm not sure I know what you mean, but I've updated the answer to maybe address this.

Comment: The function is defined in the same scope than the instanciation of tracker. I would need this to be done outside, on a separate file. But I think I have the solution, exactly as its done with flask and blueprints!